# Sending data taking too long but indexes aready create

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

I am having problems with a query that is taking 20 seconds to return results :(

In table cases and cases_cstm, i have 960,000 rows

This is My query:

```
    SELECT  cases.id ,cases_cstm.assunto_c, cases.name , cases.case_number ,
      cases.priority  , accounts.name account_name , 
      accounts.assigned_user_id account_name_owner  , 
      'Accounts' account_name_mod, cases.account_id  , 
      LTRIM(RTRIM(CONCAT(IFNULL(jt1.first_name,''),' ',IFNULL(jt1.last_name,'')))) assigned_user_name , 
      jt1.created_by assigned_user_name_owner  , 
      'Users' assigned_user_name_mod, cases.status , cases.date_entered ,
      cases.assigned_user_id  
   FROM cases  
   LEFT JOIN cases_cstm ON cases.id = cases_cstm.id_c
   LEFT JOIN  accounts accounts ON 
      cases.account_id=accounts.id AND accounts.deleted=0   AND 
      accounts.deleted=0  
   LEFT JOIN  users jt1 ON 
      cases.assigned_user_id=jt1.id AND 
      jt1.deleted=0   AND jt1.deleted=0 
   where 
     (((LTRIM(RTRIM(CONCAT(IFNULL(accounts.name,'')))) LIKE 'rodrigo fernando%' OR 
     LTRIM(RTRIM(CONCAT(IFNULL(accounts.name,'')))) LIKE 'rodrigo fernando%'))) AND 
     cases.deleted=0 ORDER BY cases.date_entered DESC LIMIT 0,11;
```

here is the indexes of the table:

```
+-------+------------+--------------------+--------------+------------------
+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+--------
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name           | Seq_in_index | Column_name |Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment 
+-------+------------+--------------------+--------------+------------------
+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------
| cases |          0 | PRIMARY            |            1 | id          | A         |      911472 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |          
| cases |          0 | case_number        |            1 | case_number | A         |      911472 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         
|
| cases |          1 | idx_case_name      |            1 | name        | A         |      911472 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         
|
| cases |          1 | idx_account_id     |            1 | account_id  | A         |      455736 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         
|
| cases |          1 | idx_cases_stat_del |            1 | assigned_user_id| A         |         106 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         
|
| cases |          1 | idx_cases_stat_del |            2 | status      | A         |         197 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         
|
| cases |          1 | idx_cases_stat_del |            3 | deleted     | A         |         214 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         
|
| cases |          1 | idx_priority       |            1 | priority    | A         |      455736 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         
|
| cases |          1 | idx_date_entered   |            1 | date_entered| A         |      455736 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         
+-------+------------+--------------------+--------------+------------------
+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------
```

[The Explain command of query(Image!)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sxJc.png)

this is the profile of query execution:

```
+--------------------+-----------+
| Status             | Duration  |
+--------------------+-----------+
| starting           |  0.000122 |
| Opening tables     |  0.000180 |
| System lock        |  0.000005 |
| Table lock         |  0.000005 |
| init               |  0.000051 |
| optimizing         |  0.000017 |
| statistics         |  0.000071 |
| preparing          |  0.000021 |
| executing          |  0.000003 |
| Sorting result     |  0.000004 |
| Sending data       | 21.595455 |
| end                |  0.000012 |
| query end          |  0.000002 |
| freeing items      |  0.000419 |
| logging slow query |  0.000005 |
| logging slow query |  0.000002 |
| cleaning up        |  0.000004 |
```

Can someone help me undertang why the query is taking so long to execute?

Thanks!!

Comment: You have lots of function calls in where clauses, may be that is the issue

Comment: As usual, Profile says the useless "Sending data".

Comment: That should not take 20 seconds.  Something else is going on.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE cases`.

Comment: your query doesn't require `left join` at all. you also have a bunch of repeated conditions like `accounts.deleted=0   AND accounts.deleted=0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change your `LEFT JOIN` to accounts to an `INNER JOIN` I don't know if that will make a drastic change, but it makes a lot more sense if you understand the difference.

What you are saying with `LEFT JOIN` is "I want all cases, whether or not they have an associated account". An `INNER JOIN` here means "Give me all cases and return all accounts for them".

The end-result of your query is the same, because you are later on filtering things out with your `WHERE` clause, but I have a feeling that this *might* be why `idx_account_id` is being ignored.

A second, probably bigger problem is your where clause:

```
 (((LTRIM(RTRIM(CONCAT(IFNULL(accounts.name,'')))) LIKE 'rodrigo fernando%' OR 
 LTRIM(RTRIM(CONCAT(IFNULL(accounts.name,'')))) LIKE 'rodrigo fernando%'))) AND
```

There's a ton of functions here, and MySQL can't optimize this using an index. Every record will be checked for this condition, and all functions you're using will be called for every record. This is most likely the biggest problem.

First, this can be simplified a bit. I think both sides of this OR statements are the same, so lets first turn this into one:

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(CONCAT(IFNULL(accounts.name,'')))) LIKE 'rodrigo fernando%'
```

Since you are adding a wildcard on one side of the switch statement, why bother with the RTRIM?

```
LTRIM(CONCAT(IFNULL(accounts.name,''))) LIKE 'rodrigo fernando%'
```

You don't need to CONCAT anything, if there's only one thing!

```
LTRIM(IFNULL(accounts.name,'')) LIKE 'rodrigo fernando%'
```

LTRIM works just fine on NULL values

```
LTRIM(accounts.name) LIKE 'rodrigo fernando%'
```

Alright, that saved us a bunch of functions. However, the last LTRIM is still a major problem as it completely still blocks mysql from using indexes. The solution is fairly simple though:

1. Update your accounts table, once:

   UPDATE accounts SET name = LTRIM(name);
2. Make sure that whenever you insert new accounts, you trim before inserting. So you're really doing this now during `INSERT` time, not `SELECT` time.
3. Change your previous WHERE clause to:

   accounts.name LIKE 'rodrigo fernando%'

Boom, you can now use an index on accounts.name and it will be fast as fuck.

Comment: Yes,  this works!! what i dit is change LEFT to INNER JOIN, in the cases to cases_cstm and cases to accounts and query executing now in 0.9 seconds.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your query as well as your indexing also. As you have indexed only on cases table, and you are using account and users table you should consider these table also while indexing. Make changes in your query as follows.

```
SELECT cases.id, cases_cstm.assunto_c, cases.name, cases.case_number, cases.priority, accounts.name account_name, accounts.assigned_user_id account_name_owner, 
'Accounts' account_name_mod, cases.account_id, LTRIM(RTRIM(CONCAT(IFNULL(jt1.first_name,''),' ',IFNULL(jt1.last_name,'')))) assigned_user_name, 
jt1.created_by assigned_user_name_owner,'Users' assigned_user_name_mod, cases.status, cases.date_entered, cases.assigned_user_id 
FROM cases  [enter link description here][1]
LEFT JOIN cases_cstm ON cases.id = cases_cstm.id_c
LEFT JOIN accounts accounts ON cases.account_id=accounts.id AND accounts.deleted=0 AND (TRIM(accounts.name) LIKE 'rodrigo fernando%' OR TRIM(accounts.name) LIKE 'rodrigo fernando%')
LEFT JOIN  users jt1 ON cases.assigned_user_id=jt1.id AND jt1.deleted=0
WHERE cases.deleted=0 ORDER BY cases.date_entered DESC LIMIT 0,11;
```

Then first delete indexes that are not being used then create indexes on tables as follows:

1. Cases - deleted, date_entered (One index with multiple column)
2. accounts - deleted, name (One index with multiple column)
3. Users - deleted

Create these indexes and make sure sequence of columns selected and used in query must same, because MySql uses any leftmost prefix of the index. If you need more details go through these links:

- [Multiple-Column Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)
- [MySQL ORDER BY / LIMIT performance](https://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem following the tips of Evert!
To be clear, this is a query that is being mounted dynamically by a system, I will still need to optimize the code to remove the functions that do not make sense in this case.
What helped me was to replace the LEFT by INNER joins in cases for cases_cstm and cases for accounts ... only with this change the query started being executed in 0.9 seconds!

Thanks for everyone's help!